# What is the maximum allowed size for a SQLite DB and can I use PetaPoco as an ORM?

Tags: .net, sqlite, petapoco

What is the maximum allowed size for a SQLite database in a Windows Forms application?
Can I use [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) as an ORM, or can you suggest a similar ORM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Concerning your max size question the limit is about 14 terabytes (http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html).

And I think you can use PetaPoco, since this lines can be found in PetaPoco.cs:

```
    enum DBType
    {
        SqlServer,
        SqlServerCE,
        MySql,
        PostgreSQL,
        Oracle,
        SQLite
    }
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted since it answers **both** questions. +1

Answer (score 4):

You can use PetaPoco. The current version 3.0.4 supports SqlLite.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your PetaPoco question:

No, you can't use PetaPoco because it doesn't support SQLite.
Quote from the [main page](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/):

> Works with SQL Server, SQL Server CE, MySQL, PostgreSQL and Oracle.

If you don't want to usw a full-blown ORM like [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) (which suppports SQLite), there are other Micro-ORMs like PetaPoco:

- [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) (made and used by the folks here at Stack Overflow)
- [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) (by [Rob Conery](http://blog.wekeroad.com/))

Dapper is completely database agnostic, Massive [explicitly supports SQLite](https://github.com/robconery/massive/commit/ef6b783a35619a459e8b6be6b85dd0973cd43cb3).